# How to listen for Key input from User?

Tags: android, kotlin, input, keyboard

I managed to get a Alert Dialog to pop up with a editText to handle input from the user. How would i handle the submit process when they hit Enter on the keyboard? I would like to refrain from using a button to submit and change the text. Hopefully i gave enough detail as i am still quite new to this. Thanks for your time.

[Phone App Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPFjy.png)

The Alert Dialog:

```
(1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        tv.setOnLongClickListener {

            //Alert Window
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            alertDialog.setTitle("NEW PRICE")
            val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
            val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            input.layoutParams = lp
            alertDialog.setView(input).show()
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
(1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        tv.setOnLongClickListener {

            //Alert Window
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            alertDialog.setTitle("NEW PRICE")
            val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
            //Alert Submit on Enter
            input.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // Input changes text
                    tv.text = input.text
                    when {
                        tv.text.startsWith("-") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                        tv.text.startsWith("+") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                    else -> {
                        tv.text = "_"
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                    }
                    }
                    // Hide Keyboard
                    // Save Price Table
                }
                false
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your custom `OnKeyListener` for the `EditText`:

```
val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
input.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        // your code here
        true
    }
    false
})
```

Comment: Huge Thanks! now i just need to find a close keyboard function to add to it and a save state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `OnEditorActionListener` for your `EditText`:

```
val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
input.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, event ->
    // If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.
    // if shift key is down, then we want to insert the '\n' char in the TextView;
    if (event == null || event.isShiftPressed) return@setOnEditorActionListener false
    // TODO: your code goes here
    return@setOnEditorActionListener true
}
```

In this example I additionally check that shift isn't pressed. It will work on all devices with any kind of keyboard.

**Note 1**. We don't need `actionId` here, but you still can set different actions for the keyboard (with `input.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND` or with xml attribute `android:imeOptions="actionSend"`) and listener will be called for any kind action on any type of keyboard. [Read Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style) to learn more about actions.

**Note 2**. I made custom wrapper for all this logic that allows me to set enter key listener in the easiest possible way. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jackqack/3988fad62ab4532809c9da39ca50ee92).

```
editText.setOnEnterActionListener {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```